# Getting rid of localhost:3000 URLs for ReactAsync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-async

Cross-posted to https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async/issues/34

When using [react-async](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async) is is common to have code which looks like:

```
var UserPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactAsync.Mixin],

  statics: {
    getUserInfo: function(username, cb) {
      superagent.get(
        'localhost:3000/api/users/' + username,
        function(err, res) {
          cb(err, res ? res.body : null);
        });
    }
  },

  getInitialStateAsync: function(cb) {
    this.type.getUserInfo(this.props.username, cb);
  },

  ...
```

The problem with this is that it *only* runs correctly in a browser running on the server.

Using the obvious solution of making the URLs relative (e.g. `'/api/users/' + username` has a subtle issue.

It seems to work, when *moving* between pages, but does not work on a page reload or initial load.  (You do not actually *move* between pages in a ReactJS app, it's just the URL that changes.)

The cause of this issue is that the server needs to call the AJAX API, during server-side rendering, but the server has no knowledge of the page origin as seen by browsers (`http://www.example.com:3000`).

Is there a way of telling this to the server-side renderer?

(I have already thought of a nasty work-around, where you use full URLs for both client and server, but this must be configured explicitly for each development, test and production server that runs the code.)

Comment: I'm in the process of coming up with a solution to this (only using AngularJS) so I'm interested to see what comes of this.

Comment: @IanBrindley Can AngularJS render server-side too?

Comment: Purely experimental. I've never looked at React in depth, so I'm just keeping my ear to the ground.

Comment: @IanBrindley Have a look at React, I used to use AngularJS, and before that KnockoutJS, but I now prefer React by a large margin.  My use-case is pages which continuously update by receiving a continuous stream of data over websockets.

Comment: Will do for sure. I'll probably give it a try with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, use a simple plugin function for superagent.  This rewrites absolute urls - but only on the server.  This means that the browser will make a request to '/api' and the server will make it to 'localhost:port/api'.

```
function fixUrlPlugin(port){
  return function fixUrl(req){
    if (process.browser) return req;
    if (req.url[0] === '/') {
        req.url = 'localhost:' + port + req.url
    }
    return req;
  };
}
```

Now somewhere in your code, you'll run this and save the output in a module.

```
app.listen(8080);
```

```
module.exports = fixUrlPlugin(8080);
```

And then your code can be come:

```
var urlPlugin = require('./path/to/that/module.js');

// ...

  statics: {
    getUserInfo: function(username, cb) {
      superagent.get('/api/users/' + username)
        .use(urlPlugin)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          cb(err, res ? res.body : null);
        });
    }
  },
```